# How to test arguments to a case class constructor?

Tags: scala, case-class

I'd like to test the arguments to my case class constructor and throw an exception if they fail certain tests.  The compiler complained when I tried to write my own apply method (Multiple 'apply' methods.

I suppose I could make it a non-case class, and do the apply/unapply constructor field stuff myself, but I had hoped not to.

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
case class Picky(i: Int, s: String) {
  require(i % 2 == 0, "i must be even")
  require(s.length < 50, "s length must be less than 50 characters")

  // ...
}
```

Comment: In the event you end up moving away from wanting client code to have to deal with exceptions (bad FP code smell) and want a preventative solution more in alignment with FP solutions like Option, Try or Either, I just posted something about it on StackOverflow's sister site, CodeReview. If you have time to look it over, I would appreciate any feedback you might have on it; i.e. help reducing boilerplate, better methods for approaching the problem space, etc.: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60645/reducing-boilerplate-when-validating-parameters-and-using-a-tuple-for-the-parame